# custom 404 page with asp.net C# 3.5 on IIS6

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-6, http-status-code-404

for error handling I have a few lines of code for catching every error in the global.asax
: `void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)` the content of the function looks like this:

```
try
    {
       Exception objErr = Server.GetLastError().GetBaseException();

       if (!(objErr is HttpException))
       {
           shop.BLL.Utility.Errorlog.WriteError(objErr, "Global.asax caught an Exception");
       }
       else
       {
           HttpException hex = (HttpException)objErr;
           if (hex.ErrorCode == 404)
               Response.Redirect("404.aspx?msg=" + hex.Message);
           else
           {
               shop.BLL.Utility.Errorlog.WriteError(hex, "Global.asax caught an HttpException code: " + hex.ErrorCode);
           }
       }

    }
    catch { }

    Server.ClearError();
```

now here is the thing: when I go to `blabla.aspx`, which does not exists, it ends up on line `shop.BLL.Utility.Errorlog.WriteError(hex, "Global.asax caught an HttpException code: " + hex.ErrorCode);` and the value of the errorcode is `-2147467259`

Why isn't it a 404?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should check with `GetHttpCode()` method.

```
 HttpException hex = (HttpException)objErr;
 if (hex.GetHttpCode() == 404)
     Response.Redirect("404.aspx?msg=" + hex.Message);
```

Answer (score 2):

The page not found doesn't throw an exception, the 404 error is an Http response code. If you are trying to set up a custom error page for 404 handling, you can set it up using the

```
<customErrors>
```

tag in your web.config

have a look at these articles...

http://aspnetresources.com/articles/CustomErrorPages
and
http://www.asp.net/hosting/tutorials/displaying-a-custom-error-page-cs

Dave

Answer (score 1):

From [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpexception_members.aspx):

`ErrorCode` Gets the HRESULT of the error. (Inherited from `ExternalException`).

`GetHttpCode()` Gets the HTTP response status code to return to the client.

The HRESULT 0x80004005 means `Generic Error`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you want to use ErrorCode - that is for the internal error. Try using GetHttpCode() on your HttpException object. That should return the 404 you are looking for.

```
if (hex.GetHttpCode() == 404)
```